# Asp.net C# connection with access 2007

Tags: asp.net

OleDbConnection con;

```
    con = new OleDbConnection("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = E:/connectivity dbms:/pcomp.accdb;");
    con.Open();
```

I got this error:

> 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection' does not contain a definition for 'open'

Answer (score 2):

The [`Open()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.open.aspx) method exists. Make sure you've spelled and cased it correctly. In the error message text it starts with a lowercase letter and I suspect you have a typo in your code.